# Prometheus avg_over_time and unless includes too much data

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

on one of my Grafana dashboards I'd love to show all metrics of instances which had some downtime during the inspected timeframe (last 12h). But filter out all all others with no downtime.

I'm using the data provided by the prometheus blackbox exporter and I'd love to get the avg_over_time for all instances which are not 100% available during the timeframe I'm looking at (e.g. 12h).

My base query looks like this:

```
avg_over_time(probe_success{job="blackbox"}[15m])
```

In order to filter everything out which wasn't behaving as expected I tried sth. like this (tried to keep it readable):

```
_base_qery_ unless on(instance) _base_qery_ < 0.95
```

But this would also include series with *instance* labels which do not appear within the `_base_qery_ < 0.95`.

From the [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) I expected this type of filtering

> vector1 unless vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of vector1 for which there are no elements in vector2 with exactly matching label sets. All matching elements in both vectors are dropped.

My workaround for the time being is this query (where 12h is the full time range I observe with Grafana):

```
    avg_over_time(probe_success{job="blackbox"}[15m]) and avg_over_time(probe_success{job="blackbox"}[12h]) < 1
```

But I'd love to get the 15 minute range version working.

Comment: I find it really difficult to parse your question. You say you want "all metrics which had some downtime" (I guess you mean "instances", not "metrics"). But then your query AFAICT returns all instances that have had more than 95% uptime, i.e. the ones without downtime. (`unless` does exactly what it says on the tin, it's just you may be using it wrong.)

And finally I don't get what's with the `15m` and `12h`: do you want the average uptime measured over 15 minutes or 12 hours? And what prevents you from using `avg_over_time(probe_success{job="blackbox"}[15m]) < 1`?

Comment: `avg_over_time(probe_success{job="blackbox"}[15m])  < 0.95` filters out everything which is above 0.95  ... that's what I want to look at. But I want all measurements for these in a longer timeframe. You're right I could use `<1` - but that doesn't answer why the `unless` is working differently.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. AFAICT `avg_over_time(probe_success{job="blackbox"}[15m]) < .95` (or `1`, or whatever) should give you exactly what you want. Replace the `15m` with `12h` and you get the targets that had less than 95% (or 100%) downtime over the past 12 hours. `foo unless foo < .95` is exactly the same as `foo >=.95`, i.e. it will give you the targets with uptime higher than 95%. Which (I am guessin, not sure) is not what you want.

Comment: E.g. you say "But this would also include series with `instance` labels which do not appear within the `_base_qery_ < 0.95`." In your particular case `unless` will __only__ return the `instance` labels that do not appear within the right side query (i.e. series with `_base_qery_ >= 0.95`). That's exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for hanging on. Yes you're right - that's what happens - BUT the documentation says: `with exactly matching label sets` ... and that's what got me thinking that the label values matter - but they don't

Comment: The label values matter. In that you need to have the exact same labels and label values on both sides for any series to get dropped. (The `__name__` label is excluded because otherwise you would have to jump through hoops to get even the most basic match working.) BTW, did you manage to work through your issue, or do you still have a question? I'm really not sure. (o:

Comment: I still have that question - but I'll try to add some example data later on - that make my issue clear